# SQL Server stored procedure performance testing

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have a task to test stored procedures performance in SQL Server. My goal is to report the average time and standard deviation of the stored procedure's execution time to the stakeholders. Realistic data input is a must here :)

My question: as I was trying to realistically stage the test I created a simple script that supposedly should measure the time it takes to perform stored procedure:

```
DECLARE @ValidCharacters varchar(20), 
        @DataLength tinyint, @LocalPart smallint, @DomainPart smallint

SET @ValidCharacters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy'
SET @DataLength = DATALENGTH (@ValidCharacters) - 1

CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTable(EmailID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), email varchar(30));

CREATE TABLE #LocalTempTableTimesOfInserting(TimesOfInsertingID int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), TimesOfInserting int);

DECLARE @counter int, @boundary int, @email varchar(25), @start DateTime, @end DateTime

SET @counter=0
SET @boundary=25

WHILE (@counter < @boundary)
BEGIN
    DBCC FREEPROCCACHE;
    DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS;

    SET @email = SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @DataLength + 1, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @DataLength + 1) + 
                 '@' + SUBSTRING(@ValidCharacters, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @DataLength + 1, ABS(CHECKSUM(NewId())) % @DataLength + 1) + '.com'
SET @start = SYSDATETIME()

    INSERT INTO #LocalTempTable VALUES (@email);

SET @end = SYSDATETIME()

INSERT INTO #LocalTempTableTimesOfInserting 
    VALUES (DATEDIFF(ns, @start, @end));

    SELECT DATEDIFF(ms, @start, @end)

    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

You see that I'm doing a micro benchmark on an insert and recording the results to a local temporary table (my idea was to export is latter to excel and do my calculations there and share it with colleagues) :)

My questions:

1. Do you have any advice how to improve the performance test - the real stored procedure is much heavier than the one in the example (I have read many a post, tried tools like SQLQueryStress - I'm really interested in doing the test this way, mainly for the interesting questions I go here);
2. Why do I get useless results in this case, like so (measuring in nanoseconds) - maybe as the operations are beginning to be simple and fast I will see such fluctuating performance, instability in results? Or maybe this is the result of SQL Server returning a cached result (even if I'm using DBCC; how to turn it off then?). Another explanation could be thread and parallel execution (different threads are executing time functions and thus they are executing them in parallel - which would explain the zeros):

[image]

Comment: The variables are `datetime`. That only has precision of `1/300` of a second, not nanoseconds! And the system time functions aren't anywhere near that accurate either.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here...Rewording and splitting the the first question about guidance on how to write your sp performance testing into another question might help you get a better answer for that one.

Comment: @MartinSmith :: 1/300 (s) will be pretty good for a larger stored procedure then. But not for a lightweight one - any suggestions on this particular point? How can I get more precise?

Comment: `datetime2(7)` has greater precision. The resolution of the system time functions is still going to be an issue though. I'd test thousands or millions of executions and take an average. Not just single executions.

Comment: @MartinSmith , yes I'm planing to do data generation and performance testing at the same time and the call count to the SP will be in millions. Thanks for the datetime2 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your second question: like you said, it's probably the result of query execution plan caching.

[Execution Plan Caching and Reuse](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

When you manually run the sp and it runs quickly, you can try executing another query and then running your sp test again. If it runs more slowly the second time around, your quick speeds are probably due to the caching.